# How to make my TypeScript object available to a third party Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, api-design

I have an Angular application and need to create an API for a third party javascript that will be added dynamically.

```
public class MyApi{
   public callSomeFunction():void{...}
   public getSomeValue():any {...}   
}
var publicApi = new MyApi();
```

How do I get the `publicApi` object into javascripts global scope?

Comment: Just curious, to understand why `publicApi` is needed. any specific use case?

Comment: @PankajParkar for our software users can dynamically build a custom UI. The API enables them to add more custom logic and interactions between components.

Comment: The reason behind asking this question is, If data is being still consumed by Angular components, directives, and service, etc. then it is a good idea to keep everything in an injection token, rather than poluting the `global` context. The other advantage you get with injectionToken-based sharing is, that testing becomes easier(Mocking is simplified)

Comment: Thanks @PankajParkar, you make a good point. In our given scenario a public API  is the most flexible option for our customers.

Comment: @PankajParkar Thanks, I don't see how DI would help in our scenario, since our customers need to use the API at runtime by sending scripts down the wire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it to the `global` object of the `client-side` which is `window` object.

```
window.publicApi = new MyApi();
```

Comment: Thanks! For anyone who uses strict Typescript: ```(window as any).publicApi = new MyApi()``` will cast ```window``` to ```any``` and allow you to add new members.

Answer (score 1):

If by global scope you mean window then:
`(window as any).publicApi  = new MyApi();`
If you just want to import it from other packages then export it by adding
`export const publicApi = new MyApi();`

And then use it depending on which module system you use:
`const {publicApi} = require('./path/to/publicApi')`
or
`import {publicApi} from './path/to/publicApi'`

Comment: Thanks @nickbullock, I didn't know that I meant window at the time.